# OAuth 2.0 Google Apps For Education approval prompt/ consent window

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script

I have a Google apps for education account and I am using app scripts to create gadgets to embed into Google sites. I have looked everywhere to try and find out if you can allow your domain users to access API's without using the approval prompt/ consent window.

The scenario is:

As a user I don't want to have to allow trusted services such as google drive, calendar etc. to use my data. As the admin of the domain I need to be able to give all users the required access. I have been through the admin.google.com settings "Manage OAuth Domain Key" and "Manage API Client Access" and the Google documentation (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer?hl=en) on the "approval_prompt" parameter, which allows:

force or auto:
Indicates whether the user should be re-prompted for consent. The default is auto, so a given user should only see the consent page for a given set of scopes the first time through the sequence. If the value is force, then the user sees a consent page even if they previously gave consent to your application for a given set of scopes.

Any info would be beneficial! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing Google services like Gmai, Drive, Calendar, etc through their APIs, this action is performed by an application.

When you install an app, you get the prompt screen and there you are authorizing that app to call those APIs and get your information.

That prompt screen is there not because you don trust the APIs but because you don't trust the application. Otherwise, any application would be able to access your information without asking you for permissions and that would be a serious issue.

As an administrator you can install applications on all your users accounts, nevertheless, it's up to them if they want that application to access their information or not.

I hope this clarifies a little bit why this is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I thought that might be the case.